# Filling a specified area of an SVG using clipping

Tags: svg

I'm wanting to achieve the below but without the green rectangle on the dark background, so only part of the area chart would be green.

[image]

I've tried using clipping but cannot get it working. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

```css
div {
  background:#282e3d;
}
path.fc.area {
    fill: red;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
}
.target-rect {
  fill: green;
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
}
```

```html
<div id="fc-area">
  <svg width="800" height="400">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect width="730" height="290"></rect>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g class="focus" transform="translate(60,10)">
      <path class="fc area" d="M0,288.69668447384043C0.9372453238555296,288.65985505468535,3.854423200796099,288.6005266165116,5.632155301144848,288.4753667429831S8.93570423761282,288.0143960108386,10.71926331508213,287.9589587043161S14.437827053363833,288.20727248008893,16.34384851501576,288.1802764351734S20.330288465943436,287.9765919592039,22.1576862452298,287.7868226914271S25.640214184277202,287.07151615283834,27.42647668823627,287.04909692190284S30.999612656513975,287.0831999428466,32.87694956031193,287.073687780887S36.830203690246734,286.90622241660844,38.69078729052597,286.72941575510896S42.45041365674173,286.4778099306502,44.141260162601625,286.0162808445688S48.02677304331524,284.41989453373185,49.59173303467728,283.75392181802766S53.43949259257706,281.6127475923156,55.231458437033346,281.2948359196133S58.80677021571377,281.9843539615754,60.681931309109004,281.7374713813279S65.03183959330704,280.2894222347443,66.67745146839223,279.67183922665987S70.23704323254584,277.70180943326255,71.9462419113987,277.53243449503947S75.36942804367148,278.1404706567283,77.03334992533598,278.58984143135757S80.78788394679032,280.3521850113018,82.65793512526962,280.4587467141525S86.44364669582467,279.26413848381424,88.29009042641447,279.22920376494534S91.93769345481327,280.371451023246,93.74056329849014,280.212838124311S97.49892134900865,278.78227418055525,99.1910361705658,278.27016026456374S103.12326300607963,277.41772039869767,104.82319147171063,276.86848130246756S108.71776099879789,275.17433811716813,110.45534677285549,274.63071313491054S114.71581233823031,273.9797379140499,116.26918450306952,273.3028067497668S120.05647713054009,270.5762319676386,121.5455450472872,269.9092682099551S125.1816906430439,268.9436969286501,126.99601791936287,268.53218010684304S131.1413348122045,267.1029694204778,132.9915380786461,267.32722801662S136.78546828482112,269.05477840919605,138.26032852165255,269.6633596201136S141.50253652297604,271.64774766545577,143.34743653558985,271.60603747986096S147.5211915977623,268.8089724689728,149.33538659366184,269.04858814551005S152.8722906473899,271.95979171990564,154.42249460759913,272.56508098024256S158.2306639485593,273.7918494855273,160.05464990874398,273.4011701857034S164.02158684116188,269.8794921329143,165.86848763895802,269.8600864919868S169.32060939004432,269.9014901858623,171.1372780819645,269.8846773509709S175.14075104707152,267.49644320871766,176.76943338310934,266.8600016959213S180.85804618051623,266.16884989286353,182.4015886842542,265.48291359280927S186.0651136837046,262.17207386480834,187.8596316575411,261.9664207580768S191.44301450880894,263.95353792361647,193.31010452961672,264.228779784618S197.42834406790158,263.91968458046864,199.30562468889994,263.9336894768083S202.92126286625148,264.6495399973608,204.57441513190642,264.3025523615704S208.1717534921776,262.2450514423263,209.66152314584372,261.54837615534643S214.4185783578776,260.1756662339692,215.46779077484652,259.2614262698211S218.95645152772101,252.41024804594892,220.736581217853,252.1546680234037S224.49900348562943,251.9791909358839,226.36873651899785,251.85957771559399S230.51290095810575,249.3691732069167,232.00089182014267,248.63817518867126S236.0381466518214,247.2615428360255,237.45136469221836,246.40040702111423S243.12895195770943,242.2289663572464,243.62856728057073,241.40846264733315S247.66335919828222,230.13930329272767,248.53399286543888,229.26057830916648S252.35738067567513,232.25270869382518,254.17371826779492,231.8426185025015S259.38834923214273,225.6804306308775,259.987555998009,226.5555838209107S265.03898499310515,246.6810551697293,265.4380288700846,247.43322309844822S269.10857826069366,251.22174303875693,270.88850174216026,250.87594335622828S275.96643976505385,245.56432631687568,276.5206570433051,244.72822861019247S281.1866690662163,235.43842519504528,281.78187738510036,234.5967947087255S285.4006394699915,229.3893788416373,287.23235025717605,229.6786229118969S292.00257429110366,235.84507516258697,293.0461879873901,236.7607902993301S296.50163485287294,239.66818547241044,298.3149784303966,239.58873908250658S303.2272690117024,235.14755393159672,303.9471337315414,236.0722462477741S308.9147601860093,253.718036518508,309.76097146175545,254.63834478080219S313.3752226454315,256.04586607733904,315.0297619047619,256.65479521750194S319.73705069245494,260.7759723798972,321.0328521652563,261.62214873229885S324.3225505341482,263.8698388699195,326.11996017919364,264.056643771729S330.02805065200045,262.54329114470255,331.93379790940764,262.48282879674383S335.8140160022578,262.99955725697805,337.56595321055255,262.7533282455694S341.89722122665665,258.35991057473854,342.6530612244898,257.4908844229628S347.1292475937354,251.51131009473136,348.0959639953542,250.6054439074027S352.06995465629285,248.0254194570081,353.5464368674299,247.28567794454338S358.09015655484814,245.9812153589036,359.17859216857477,245.07250063597047S363.2414533199022,238.96277722954108,364.6290650406504,238.113287543458S369.16327884672495,237.27004627156865,370.6245851999337,236.49029085050452S374.44691559037,231.51117085856032,375.8933756429401,230.80980242516745S379.6415884975412,230.3003518193414,381.34384851501574,229.75239548884932S385.887556900598,226.8193006372745,387.165256346441,225.96540320529127S390.5743125666272,222.05198463587274,392.43404678944745,222.35054693462223S396.74985913111396,228.3994866854273,398.6112493777999,228.57203425761045S403.1277899645576,225.19281573949056,403.69835739173715,224.3915882303061S408.3516571246911,215.05043479765573,408.7854654056745,214.2847451878233S413.07123955254883,206.47589409662112,414.4100506056081,205.60417196642075S418.5187716900726,206.5138080572246,420.22388833582215,207.0058509285169S423.70619249907867,208.7865373553125,425.4926787788286,208.7763927753752S429.16027543521386,206.4724119899279,430.9431516509042,206.8828966335962S435.65277345480683,212.50373431183638,436.7569893811183,211.57975069956754S441.76647623529664,198.8337040835061,442.20746225319397,198.05477825828882S446.55736186750676,193.2323022020739,447.6579351252696,192.3251081149835S451.9963056231944,189.799876064747,453.29766052762574,188.95616043415586S457.5997539959662,186.07835912935468,458.7481333997014,185.14457729161367S463.7086883607466,180.52078578152785,464.7436535589846,179.58704316119733S468.41734761692413,175.42088276800533,470.012444001991,174.9639616721784S473.3334372949548,176.32919673699564,475.09955201592834,176.51318578817944S478.84862543998605,175.9383174375817,480.7241372158619,175.9721868905283S484.7701855187964,176.09109830127252,486.35629251700675,176.7345035190367S491.13242475760694,181.66973277038971,491.8067653890825,180.79199525142036S496.3268889977185,163.469105221547,497.25723826115814,162.54557788518613S501.06995478204584,164.1143745012377,502.889393562303,164.43907402696516S507.07897299284855,166.41394578768112,508.5215488634478,165.5948443992199S512.4900214058888,157.72512238648696,514.3353865936618,157.79954210124652S517.8243955096699,165.27126984148333,519.6117471378795,165.29975409141016S524.7155899305405,158.46136576790747,525.0622200099551,157.7257695242941S530.9543075160371,141.03888270525565,531.0577401692384,140.61053167133045S536.2445065451735,112.38194049993086,536.3265306122449,112.01136267277201S540.9457591587098,93.88413796904958,541.5953210552514,93.00262867802935S546.0954864418143,97.35168296967373,547.4015886842542,98.19129992368354S550.8537537376521,100.23792342879042,552.6703791272606,100.25693207835158S557.3408848446342,99.10512084978787,558.3025344284055,98.1667090646994S563.686565068171,89.89469617963005,563.9346897295503,89.26481811243963S567.5075778633568,70.54355238852968,569.385162601626,70.20690239972866S573.8148587256071,69.17493965867578,575.5623651899784,69.59213092512509S579.6667972240341,92.69290383194065,580.4677907748465,93.56821843466466S584.8490873102971,95.12253592840435,586.1075161772026,96.02730433307897S591.8051399697514,113.40326949748446,591.9213539074167,113.85567709658274S597.0388521636696,138.8748043083934,597.3718267794923,139.57771559399646S601.1637537985384,143.03590230477457,602.822299651568,143.43848045450693S606.1241312500977,143.02365007387948,607.9094076655052,143.02043585177645S611.688461361453,143.01982202048495,613.5339928654388,142.99584499279234S618.2012997386864,138.688457234437,618.9844657375146,139.62689731196474S623.345853225515,158.29111471515148,624.9799858967978,157.70117866530993S629.8897463949365,139.22666089894315,630.067093910735,138.69244467056728S634.5703589033614,126.76252019510356,635.6992492118799,125.8068345628763S640.9718964320548,130.27399495240886,641.6947693711631,129.37250911557706S646.5596373318158,114.24880729529377,646.7818773851004,113.65895022470959S650.9664487695967,101.92721714182059,652.4216027874564,101.14220300178073S656.8233426234658,98.55322218483015,658.0537580886013,99.44543373187486S662.7248166716139,119.27090448082704,663.6859133897461,120.22470957347579S668.6498608920278,111.22111853268562,669.4997511199601,110.31459340286612S674.2009107106109,107.39396288171181,674.5868591338975,106.67514627321293S679.691762951253,88.71202414979183,679.8480794756928,88.20741117612143S684.9223389929158,72.9010859870625,685.2985523477684,72.14958025947595S690.3114650868745,66.96642227502008,691.1123900779824,66.05104723140848S696.0749010008137,60.214652610922435,696.3811805209889,59.53446960061054S701.2574438689948,42.41784735662628,702.0133358221337,41.48477910624947S707.1501027267602,46.65364238712837,707.8271735523477,45.76358856949041S712.9863588914144,28.47391547391859,713.0959639953543,28.0335792419232S717.3749047826867,0.46278344058819765,719.0990542558486,0S723.2991950758052,20.117025447633416,724.186162269786,21.025184431442405S729.8188246086225,9.279686574153441,730,8.901890952259818L730,290C729.0310270449643,290,726.0029865604779,290,724.186162269786,290S720.9474206349206,290,719.0990542558486,290S714.9746107792711,290,713.0959639953543,290S709.6742782478846,290,707.8271735523477,290S703.9210013273603,290,702.0133358221337,290S698.1980048116808,290,696.3811805209889,290S692.959494773519,290,691.1123900779824,290S687.17593744815,290,685.2985523477684,290S681.6333616780046,290,679.8480794756928,290S676.3115805265196,290,674.5868591338975,290S671.316575410652,290,669.4997511199601,290S665.5935788949726,290,663.6859133897461,290S659.9311431889829,290,658.0537580886013,290S654.3002495713732,290,652.4216027874564,290S648.5696829544827,290,646.7818773851004,290S643.5418740666998,290,641.6947693711631,290S637.6371951219512,290,635.6992492118799,290S631.853637796582,290,630.067093910735,290S626.8270905923345,290,624.9799858967978,290S620.8921312427411,290,618.9844657375146,290S615.3798358774403,290,613.5339928654388,290S609.694689867817,290,607.9094076655052,290S604.5785631325701,290,602.822299651568,290S599.1886510701842,290,597.3718267794923,290S593.7987390077983,290,591.9213539074167,290S588.0164433659643,290,586.1075161772026,290S582.2253159393839,290,580.4677907748465,290S577.4094698855151,290,575.5623651899784,290S571.3231085116973,290,569.385162601626,290S565.7817944250871,290,563.9346897295503,290S560.1799195287871,290,558.3025344284055,290S554.4872034179525,290,552.6703791272606,290S549.2474316962557,290,547.4015886842542,290S543.4411640672529,290,541.5953210552514,290S538.0827940932471,290,536.3265306122449,290S532.93512526962,290,531.0577401692384,290S526.9698855151817,290,525.0622200099551,290S521.3995527072618,290,519.6117471378795,290S516.1837529727338,290,514.3353865936618,290S510.42921436867425,290,508.5215488634478,290S504.7667786626846,290,502.889393562303,290S499.1043429566949,290,497.25723826115814,290S493.6235896797744,290,491.8067653890825,290S488.2033972125435,290,486.35629251700675,290S482.6002606327083,290,480.7241372158619,290S476.88483421824014,290,475.09955201592834,290S471.73842707814833,290,470.012444001991,290S466.6210386593662,290,464.7436535589846,290S460.65579890492785,290,458.7481333997014,290S455.14602690669767,290,453.29766052762574,290S449.50630150434154,290,447.6579351252696,290S444.02428654388586,290,442.20746225319397,290S438.6343744814999,290,436.7569893811183,290S432.82053675128583,290,430.9431516509042,290S427.27922266467556,290,425.4926787788286,290S422.0709930313589,290,420.22388833582215,290S416.3164544272994,290,414.4100506056081,290S410.5707476079863,290,408.7854654056745,290S405.39406006304955,290,403.69835739173715,290S400.4886344781815,290,398.6112493777999,290S394.3417122946739,290,392.43404678944745,290S389.01362272551296,290,387.165256346441,290S383.2224952989326,290,381.34384851501574,290S377.6799195287871,290,375.8933756429401,290S372.5019703003153,290,370.6245851999337,290S366.5367305458769,290,364.6290650406504,290S361.0256968641115,290,359.17859216857477,290S355.3935415629667,290,353.5464368674299,290S349.9115266025109,290,348.0959639953542,290S344.40806302195676,290,342.6530612244898,290S339.3524970963996,290,337.56595321055255,290S333.8414634146341,290,331.93379790940764,290S327.93678446988554,290,326.11996017919364,290S322.88121854432825,290,321.0328521652563,290S316.9084086886787,290,315.0297619047619,290S311.6080761572922,290,309.76097146175545,290S305.85479923676786,290,303.9471337315414,290S300.1318027210885,290,298.3149784303966,290S294.89329268292687,290,293.0461879873901,290S289.10973535755767,290,287.23235025717605,290S283.56715958741216,290,281.78187738510036,290S278.33621965046177,290,276.5206570433051,290S272.735606437697,290,270.88850174216026,290S267.2548531607765,290,265.4380288700846,290S261.8649410983906,290,259.987555998009,290S256.08264545655663,290,254.17371826779492,290S250.29151802997623,290,248.53399286543888,290S245.4756719761075,290,243.62856728057073,290S239.3893106022897,290,237.45136469221836,290S233.84799651567943,290,232.00089182014267,290S228.24612161937947,290,226.36873651899785,290S222.5534055085449,290,220.736581217853,290S217.31363378684807,290,215.46779077484652,290S211.4770857530004,290,209.66152314584372,290S206.3003982080637,290,204.57441513190642,290S201.18300978928156,290,199.30562468889994,290S195.2177700348432,290,193.31010452961672,290S189.6777176317682,290,187.8596316575411,290S184.24995506332615,290,182.4015886842542,290S178.64681848349096,290,176.76943338310934,290S172.9541023726564,290,171.1372780819645,290S167.71559233449477,290,165.86848763895802,290S161.96231541397046,290,160.05464990874398,290S156.20903849344614,290,154.42249460759913,290S151.1812296056634,290,149.33538659366184,290S145.1932795475914,290,143.34743653558985,290S139.98631159780984,290,138.26032852165255,290S134.86892317902772,290,132.9915380786461,290S128.90368342458936,290,126.99601791936287,290S123.33335061666943,290,121.5455450472872,290S118.11755088214147,290,116.26918450306952,290S112.36301227808198,290,110.45534677285549,290S106.70057657209225,290,104.82319147171063,290S101.03814086610254,290,99.1910361705658,290S95.55738758918203,290,93.74056329849014,290S90.13719512195122,290,88.29009042641447,290S84.53405854211603,290,82.65793512526962,290S78.8186321276478,290,77.03334992533598,290S73.67222498755599,290,71.9462419113987,290S68.55483656877385,290,66.67745146839223,290S62.589596814335486,290,60.681931309109004,290S57.0798248161053,290,55.231458437033346,290S51.44009941374924,290,49.59173303467728,290S45.95808445329351,290,44.141260162601625,290S40.568172390907584,290,38.69078729052597,290S34.754334660693544,290,32.87694956031193,290S29.21302057408329,290,27.42647668823627,290S24.004790940766554,290,22.1576862452298,290S18.25025233670704,290,16.34384851501576,290S12.50454551739395,290,10.71926331508213,290S7.418699186991869,290,5.632155301144848,290S0.938692550190808,290,0,290Z"></path>
      <g>
        <rect x="0" y="46.550496056982965" width="100%" height="147.5451539048588" class="target-rect"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example using clip paths.

Note that I have reversed the behaviour and used the graph to clip the red and green rectangles.  I did it this way so that the large graph path only gets included once.

There are other ways to only include the graph once - for example, with a `<use>` element.  But I think this way is a little more easy to understand.

```css
.fc.area {
  fill: red;
}
.target-rect {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="fc-area">
  <svg width="800" height="400">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="graph">
        <path d="M0,288C0,288,3,288,5,288S8,288,10,287S14,288,16,288S20,287,22,287S25,287,27,287S30,287,32,287S36,286,38,286S42,286,44,286S48,284,49,283S53,281,55,281S58,281,60,281S65,280,66,279S70,277,71,277S75,278,77,278S80,280,82,280S86,279,88,279S91,280,93,280S97,278,99,278S103,277,104,276S108,275,110,274S114,273,116,273S120,270,121,269S125,268,126,268S131,267,132,267S136,269,138,269S141,271,143,271S147,268,149,269S152,271,154,272S158,273,160,273S164,269,165,269S169,269,171,269S175,267,176,266S180,266,182,265S186,262,187,261S191,263,193,264S197,263,199,263S202,264,204,264S208,262,209,261S214,260,215,259S218,252,220,252S224,251,226,251S230,249,232,248S236,247,237,246S243,242,243,241S247,230,248,229S252,232,254,231S259,225,259,226S265,246,265,247S269,251,270,250S275,245,276,244S281,235,281,234S285,229,287,229S292,235,293,236S296,239,298,239S303,235,303,236S308,253,309,254S313,256,315,256S319,260,321,261S324,263,326,264S330,262,331,262S335,262,337,262S341,258,342,257S347,251,348,250S352,248,353,247S358,245,359,245S363,238,364,238S369,237,370,236S374,231,375,230S379,230,381,229S385,226,387,225S390,222,392,222S396,228,398,228S403,225,403,224S408,215,408,214S413,206,414,205S418,206,420,207S423,208,425,208S429,206,430,206S435,212,436,211S441,198,442,198S446,193,447,192S451,189,453,188S457,186,458,185S463,180,464,179S468,175,470,174S473,176,475,176S478,175,480,175S484,176,486,176S491,181,491,180S496,163,497,162S501,164,502,164S507,166,508,165S512,157,514,157S517,165,519,165S524,158,525,157S530,141,531,140S536,112,536,112S540,93,541,93S546,97,547,98S550,100,552,100S557,99,558,98S563,89,563,89S567,70,569,70S573,69,575,69S579,92,580,93S584,95,586,96S591,113,591,113S597,138,597,139S601,143,602,143S606,143,607,143S611,143,613,142S618,138,618,139S623,158,624,157S629,139,630,138S634,126,635,125S640,130,641,129S646,114,646,113S650,101,652,101S656,98,658,99S662,119,663,120S668,111,669,110S674,107,674,106S679,88,679,88S684,72,685,72S690,66,691,66S696,60,696,59S701,42,702,41S707,46,707,45S712,28,713,28S717,0,719,0S723,20,724,21S729,9,730,8L730,290C729,290,726,290,724,290S720,290,719,290S714,290,713,290S709,290,707,290S703,290,702,290S698,290,696,290S692,290,691,290S687,290,685,290S681,290,679,290S676,290,674,290S671,290,669,290S665,290,663,290S659,290,658,290S654,290,652,290S648,290,646,290S643,290,641,290S637,290,635,290S631,290,630,290S626,290,624,290S620,290,618,290S615,290,613,290S609,290,607,290S604,290,602,290S599,290,597,290S593,290,591,290S588,290,586,290S582,290,580,290S577,290,575,290S571,290,569,290S565,290,563,290S560,290,558,290S554,290,552,290S549,290,547,290S543,290,541,290S538,290,536,290S532,290,531,290S526,290,525,290S521,290,519,290S516,290,514,290S510,290,508,290S504,290,502,290S499,290,497,290S493,290,491,290S488,290,486,290S482,290,480,290S476,290,475,290S471,290,470,290S466,290,464,290S460,290,458,290S455,290,453,290S449,290,447,290S444,290,442,290S438,290,436,290S432,290,430,290S427,290,425,290S422,290,420,290S416,290,414,290S410,290,408,290S405,290,403,290S400,290,398,290S394,290,392,290S389,290,387,290S383,290,381,290S377,290,375,290S372,290,370,290S366,290,364,290S361,290,359,290S355,290,353,290S349,290,348,290S344,290,342,290S339,290,337,290S333,290,331,290S327,290,326,290S322,290,321,290S316,290,315,290S311,290,309,290S305,290,303,290S300,290,298,290S294,290,293,290S289,290,287,290S283,290,281,290S278,290,276,290S272,290,270,290S267,290,265,290S261,290,259,290S256,290,254,290S250,290,248,290S245,290,243,290S239,290,237,290S233,290,232,290S228,290,226,290S222,290,220,290S217,290,215,290S211,290,209,290S206,290,204,290S201,290,199,290S195,290,193,290S189,290,187,290S184,290,182,290S178,290,176,290S172,290,171,290S167,290,165,290S161,290,160,290S156,290,154,290S151,290,149,290S145,290,143,290S139,290,138,290S134,290,132,290S128,290,126,290S123,290,121,290S118,290,116,290S112,290,110,290S106,290,104,290S101,290,99,290S95,290,93,290S90,290,88,290S84,290,82,290S78,290,77,290S73,290,71,290S68,290,66,290S62,290,60,290S57,290,55,290S51,290,49,290S45,290,44,290S40,290,38,290S34,290,32,290S29,290,27,290S24,290,22,290S18,290,16,290S12,290,10,290S7,290,5,290S0,290,0,290Z"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect class="fc area" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#graph)"/>
    <g class="focus" clip-path="url(#graph)">
      <rect x="0" y="46.550496056982965" width="100%" height="147.5451539048588" class="target-rect"></rect>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a linearGradient and not using a clip-path at all. The double stops force a hard colour transition.

```css
path.fc.area {
    fill: url(#gradient);
}
```

```html
<div id="fc-area">
  <svg width="800" height="400">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x2="0%" y2="100%">x
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="20%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="green" offset="20%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="green" offset="50%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="50%"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g class="focus" transform="translate(60,10)">
      <path class="fc area" d="M0,288.69668447384043C0.9372453238555296,288.65985505468535,3.854423200796099,288.6005266165116,5.632155301144848,288.4753667429831S8.93570423761282,288.0143960108386,10.71926331508213,287.9589587043161S14.437827053363833,288.20727248008893,16.34384851501576,288.1802764351734S20.330288465943436,287.9765919592039,22.1576862452298,287.7868226914271S25.640214184277202,287.07151615283834,27.42647668823627,287.04909692190284S30.999612656513975,287.0831999428466,32.87694956031193,287.073687780887S36.830203690246734,286.90622241660844,38.69078729052597,286.72941575510896S42.45041365674173,286.4778099306502,44.141260162601625,286.0162808445688S48.02677304331524,284.41989453373185,49.59173303467728,283.75392181802766S53.43949259257706,281.6127475923156,55.231458437033346,281.2948359196133S58.80677021571377,281.9843539615754,60.681931309109004,281.7374713813279S65.03183959330704,280.2894222347443,66.67745146839223,279.67183922665987S70.23704323254584,277.70180943326255,71.9462419113987,277.53243449503947S75.36942804367148,278.1404706567283,77.03334992533598,278.58984143135757S80.78788394679032,280.3521850113018,82.65793512526962,280.4587467141525S86.44364669582467,279.26413848381424,88.29009042641447,279.22920376494534S91.93769345481327,280.371451023246,93.74056329849014,280.212838124311S97.49892134900865,278.78227418055525,99.1910361705658,278.27016026456374S103.12326300607963,277.41772039869767,104.82319147171063,276.86848130246756S108.71776099879789,275.17433811716813,110.45534677285549,274.63071313491054S114.71581233823031,273.9797379140499,116.26918450306952,273.3028067497668S120.05647713054009,270.5762319676386,121.5455450472872,269.9092682099551S125.1816906430439,268.9436969286501,126.99601791936287,268.53218010684304S131.1413348122045,267.1029694204778,132.9915380786461,267.32722801662S136.78546828482112,269.05477840919605,138.26032852165255,269.6633596201136S141.50253652297604,271.64774766545577,143.34743653558985,271.60603747986096S147.5211915977623,268.8089724689728,149.33538659366184,269.04858814551005S152.8722906473899,271.95979171990564,154.42249460759913,272.56508098024256S158.2306639485593,273.7918494855273,160.05464990874398,273.4011701857034S164.02158684116188,269.8794921329143,165.86848763895802,269.8600864919868S169.32060939004432,269.9014901858623,171.1372780819645,269.8846773509709S175.14075104707152,267.49644320871766,176.76943338310934,266.8600016959213S180.85804618051623,266.16884989286353,182.4015886842542,265.48291359280927S186.0651136837046,262.17207386480834,187.8596316575411,261.9664207580768S191.44301450880894,263.95353792361647,193.31010452961672,264.228779784618S197.42834406790158,263.91968458046864,199.30562468889994,263.9336894768083S202.92126286625148,264.6495399973608,204.57441513190642,264.3025523615704S208.1717534921776,262.2450514423263,209.66152314584372,261.54837615534643S214.4185783578776,260.1756662339692,215.46779077484652,259.2614262698211S218.95645152772101,252.41024804594892,220.736581217853,252.1546680234037S224.49900348562943,251.9791909358839,226.36873651899785,251.85957771559399S230.51290095810575,249.3691732069167,232.00089182014267,248.63817518867126S236.0381466518214,247.2615428360255,237.45136469221836,246.40040702111423S243.12895195770943,242.2289663572464,243.62856728057073,241.40846264733315S247.66335919828222,230.13930329272767,248.53399286543888,229.26057830916648S252.35738067567513,232.25270869382518,254.17371826779492,231.8426185025015S259.38834923214273,225.6804306308775,259.987555998009,226.5555838209107S265.03898499310515,246.6810551697293,265.4380288700846,247.43322309844822S269.10857826069366,251.22174303875693,270.88850174216026,250.87594335622828S275.96643976505385,245.56432631687568,276.5206570433051,244.72822861019247S281.1866690662163,235.43842519504528,281.78187738510036,234.5967947087255S285.4006394699915,229.3893788416373,287.23235025717605,229.6786229118969S292.00257429110366,235.84507516258697,293.0461879873901,236.7607902993301S296.50163485287294,239.66818547241044,298.3149784303966,239.58873908250658S303.2272690117024,235.14755393159672,303.9471337315414,236.0722462477741S308.9147601860093,253.718036518508,309.76097146175545,254.63834478080219S313.3752226454315,256.04586607733904,315.0297619047619,256.65479521750194S319.73705069245494,260.7759723798972,321.0328521652563,261.62214873229885S324.3225505341482,263.8698388699195,326.11996017919364,264.056643771729S330.02805065200045,262.54329114470255,331.93379790940764,262.48282879674383S335.8140160022578,262.99955725697805,337.56595321055255,262.7533282455694S341.89722122665665,258.35991057473854,342.6530612244898,257.4908844229628S347.1292475937354,251.51131009473136,348.0959639953542,250.6054439074027S352.06995465629285,248.0254194570081,353.5464368674299,247.28567794454338S358.09015655484814,245.9812153589036,359.17859216857477,245.07250063597047S363.2414533199022,238.96277722954108,364.6290650406504,238.113287543458S369.16327884672495,237.27004627156865,370.6245851999337,236.49029085050452S374.44691559037,231.51117085856032,375.8933756429401,230.80980242516745S379.6415884975412,230.3003518193414,381.34384851501574,229.75239548884932S385.887556900598,226.8193006372745,387.165256346441,225.96540320529127S390.5743125666272,222.05198463587274,392.43404678944745,222.35054693462223S396.74985913111396,228.3994866854273,398.6112493777999,228.57203425761045S403.1277899645576,225.19281573949056,403.69835739173715,224.3915882303061S408.3516571246911,215.05043479765573,408.7854654056745,214.2847451878233S413.07123955254883,206.47589409662112,414.4100506056081,205.60417196642075S418.5187716900726,206.5138080572246,420.22388833582215,207.0058509285169S423.70619249907867,208.7865373553125,425.4926787788286,208.7763927753752S429.16027543521386,206.4724119899279,430.9431516509042,206.8828966335962S435.65277345480683,212.50373431183638,436.7569893811183,211.57975069956754S441.76647623529664,198.8337040835061,442.20746225319397,198.05477825828882S446.55736186750676,193.2323022020739,447.6579351252696,192.3251081149835S451.9963056231944,189.799876064747,453.29766052762574,188.95616043415586S457.5997539959662,186.07835912935468,458.7481333997014,185.14457729161367S463.7086883607466,180.52078578152785,464.7436535589846,179.58704316119733S468.41734761692413,175.42088276800533,470.012444001991,174.9639616721784S473.3334372949548,176.32919673699564,475.09955201592834,176.51318578817944S478.84862543998605,175.9383174375817,480.7241372158619,175.9721868905283S484.7701855187964,176.09109830127252,486.35629251700675,176.7345035190367S491.13242475760694,181.66973277038971,491.8067653890825,180.79199525142036S496.3268889977185,163.469105221547,497.25723826115814,162.54557788518613S501.06995478204584,164.1143745012377,502.889393562303,164.43907402696516S507.07897299284855,166.41394578768112,508.5215488634478,165.5948443992199S512.4900214058888,157.72512238648696,514.3353865936618,157.79954210124652S517.8243955096699,165.27126984148333,519.6117471378795,165.29975409141016S524.7155899305405,158.46136576790747,525.0622200099551,157.7257695242941S530.9543075160371,141.03888270525565,531.0577401692384,140.61053167133045S536.2445065451735,112.38194049993086,536.3265306122449,112.01136267277201S540.9457591587098,93.88413796904958,541.5953210552514,93.00262867802935S546.0954864418143,97.35168296967373,547.4015886842542,98.19129992368354S550.8537537376521,100.23792342879042,552.6703791272606,100.25693207835158S557.3408848446342,99.10512084978787,558.3025344284055,98.1667090646994S563.686565068171,89.89469617963005,563.9346897295503,89.26481811243963S567.5075778633568,70.54355238852968,569.385162601626,70.20690239972866S573.8148587256071,69.17493965867578,575.5623651899784,69.59213092512509S579.6667972240341,92.69290383194065,580.4677907748465,93.56821843466466S584.8490873102971,95.12253592840435,586.1075161772026,96.02730433307897S591.8051399697514,113.40326949748446,591.9213539074167,113.85567709658274S597.0388521636696,138.8748043083934,597.3718267794923,139.57771559399646S601.1637537985384,143.03590230477457,602.822299651568,143.43848045450693S606.1241312500977,143.02365007387948,607.9094076655052,143.02043585177645S611.688461361453,143.01982202048495,613.5339928654388,142.99584499279234S618.2012997386864,138.688457234437,618.9844657375146,139.62689731196474S623.345853225515,158.29111471515148,624.9799858967978,157.70117866530993S629.8897463949365,139.22666089894315,630.067093910735,138.69244467056728S634.5703589033614,126.76252019510356,635.6992492118799,125.8068345628763S640.9718964320548,130.27399495240886,641.6947693711631,129.37250911557706S646.5596373318158,114.24880729529377,646.7818773851004,113.65895022470959S650.9664487695967,101.92721714182059,652.4216027874564,101.14220300178073S656.8233426234658,98.55322218483015,658.0537580886013,99.44543373187486S662.7248166716139,119.27090448082704,663.6859133897461,120.22470957347579S668.6498608920278,111.22111853268562,669.4997511199601,110.31459340286612S674.2009107106109,107.39396288171181,674.5868591338975,106.67514627321293S679.691762951253,88.71202414979183,679.8480794756928,88.20741117612143S684.9223389929158,72.9010859870625,685.2985523477684,72.14958025947595S690.3114650868745,66.96642227502008,691.1123900779824,66.05104723140848S696.0749010008137,60.214652610922435,696.3811805209889,59.53446960061054S701.2574438689948,42.41784735662628,702.0133358221337,41.48477910624947S707.1501027267602,46.65364238712837,707.8271735523477,45.76358856949041S712.9863588914144,28.47391547391859,713.0959639953543,28.0335792419232S717.3749047826867,0.46278344058819765,719.0990542558486,0S723.2991950758052,20.117025447633416,724.186162269786,21.025184431442405S729.8188246086225,9.279686574153441,730,8.901890952259818L730,290C729.0310270449643,290,726.0029865604779,290,724.186162269786,290S720.9474206349206,290,719.0990542558486,290S714.9746107792711,290,713.0959639953543,290S709.6742782478846,290,707.8271735523477,290S703.9210013273603,290,702.0133358221337,290S698.1980048116808,290,696.3811805209889,290S692.959494773519,290,691.1123900779824,290S687.17593744815,290,685.2985523477684,290S681.6333616780046,290,679.8480794756928,290S676.3115805265196,290,674.5868591338975,290S671.316575410652,290,669.4997511199601,290S665.5935788949726,290,663.6859133897461,290S659.9311431889829,290,658.0537580886013,290S654.3002495713732,290,652.4216027874564,290S648.5696829544827,290,646.7818773851004,290S643.5418740666998,290,641.6947693711631,290S637.6371951219512,290,635.6992492118799,290S631.853637796582,290,630.067093910735,290S626.8270905923345,290,624.9799858967978,290S620.8921312427411,290,618.9844657375146,290S615.3798358774403,290,613.5339928654388,290S609.694689867817,290,607.9094076655052,290S604.5785631325701,290,602.822299651568,290S599.1886510701842,290,597.3718267794923,290S593.7987390077983,290,591.9213539074167,290S588.0164433659643,290,586.1075161772026,290S582.2253159393839,290,580.4677907748465,290S577.4094698855151,290,575.5623651899784,290S571.3231085116973,290,569.385162601626,290S565.7817944250871,290,563.9346897295503,290S560.1799195287871,290,558.3025344284055,290S554.4872034179525,290,552.6703791272606,290S549.2474316962557,290,547.4015886842542,290S543.4411640672529,290,541.5953210552514,290S538.0827940932471,290,536.3265306122449,290S532.93512526962,290,531.0577401692384,290S526.9698855151817,290,525.0622200099551,290S521.3995527072618,290,519.6117471378795,290S516.1837529727338,290,514.3353865936618,290S510.42921436867425,290,508.5215488634478,290S504.7667786626846,290,502.889393562303,290S499.1043429566949,290,497.25723826115814,290S493.6235896797744,290,491.8067653890825,290S488.2033972125435,290,486.35629251700675,290S482.6002606327083,290,480.7241372158619,290S476.88483421824014,290,475.09955201592834,290S471.73842707814833,290,470.012444001991,290S466.6210386593662,290,464.7436535589846,290S460.65579890492785,290,458.7481333997014,290S455.14602690669767,290,453.29766052762574,290S449.50630150434154,290,447.6579351252696,290S444.02428654388586,290,442.20746225319397,290S438.6343744814999,290,436.7569893811183,290S432.82053675128583,290,430.9431516509042,290S427.27922266467556,290,425.4926787788286,290S422.0709930313589,290,420.22388833582215,290S416.3164544272994,290,414.4100506056081,290S410.5707476079863,290,408.7854654056745,290S405.39406006304955,290,403.69835739173715,290S400.4886344781815,290,398.6112493777999,290S394.3417122946739,290,392.43404678944745,290S389.01362272551296,290,387.165256346441,290S383.2224952989326,290,381.34384851501574,290S377.6799195287871,290,375.8933756429401,290S372.5019703003153,290,370.6245851999337,290S366.5367305458769,290,364.6290650406504,290S361.0256968641115,290,359.17859216857477,290S355.3935415629667,290,353.5464368674299,290S349.9115266025109,290,348.0959639953542,290S344.40806302195676,290,342.6530612244898,290S339.3524970963996,290,337.56595321055255,290S333.8414634146341,290,331.93379790940764,290S327.93678446988554,290,326.11996017919364,290S322.88121854432825,290,321.0328521652563,290S316.9084086886787,290,315.0297619047619,290S311.6080761572922,290,309.76097146175545,290S305.85479923676786,290,303.9471337315414,290S300.1318027210885,290,298.3149784303966,290S294.89329268292687,290,293.0461879873901,290S289.10973535755767,290,287.23235025717605,290S283.56715958741216,290,281.78187738510036,290S278.33621965046177,290,276.5206570433051,290S272.735606437697,290,270.88850174216026,290S267.2548531607765,290,265.4380288700846,290S261.8649410983906,290,259.987555998009,290S256.08264545655663,290,254.17371826779492,290S250.29151802997623,290,248.53399286543888,290S245.4756719761075,290,243.62856728057073,290S239.3893106022897,290,237.45136469221836,290S233.84799651567943,290,232.00089182014267,290S228.24612161937947,290,226.36873651899785,290S222.5534055085449,290,220.736581217853,290S217.31363378684807,290,215.46779077484652,290S211.4770857530004,290,209.66152314584372,290S206.3003982080637,290,204.57441513190642,290S201.18300978928156,290,199.30562468889994,290S195.2177700348432,290,193.31010452961672,290S189.6777176317682,290,187.8596316575411,290S184.24995506332615,290,182.4015886842542,290S178.64681848349096,290,176.76943338310934,290S172.9541023726564,290,171.1372780819645,290S167.71559233449477,290,165.86848763895802,290S161.96231541397046,290,160.05464990874398,290S156.20903849344614,290,154.42249460759913,290S151.1812296056634,290,149.33538659366184,290S145.1932795475914,290,143.34743653558985,290S139.98631159780984,290,138.26032852165255,290S134.86892317902772,290,132.9915380786461,290S128.90368342458936,290,126.99601791936287,290S123.33335061666943,290,121.5455450472872,290S118.11755088214147,290,116.26918450306952,290S112.36301227808198,290,110.45534677285549,290S106.70057657209225,290,104.82319147171063,290S101.03814086610254,290,99.1910361705658,290S95.55738758918203,290,93.74056329849014,290S90.13719512195122,290,88.29009042641447,290S84.53405854211603,290,82.65793512526962,290S78.8186321276478,290,77.03334992533598,290S73.67222498755599,290,71.9462419113987,290S68.55483656877385,290,66.67745146839223,290S62.589596814335486,290,60.681931309109004,290S57.0798248161053,290,55.231458437033346,290S51.44009941374924,290,49.59173303467728,290S45.95808445329351,290,44.141260162601625,290S40.568172390907584,290,38.69078729052597,290S34.754334660693544,290,32.87694956031193,290S29.21302057408329,290,27.42647668823627,290S24.004790940766554,290,22.1576862452298,290S18.25025233670704,290,16.34384851501576,290S12.50454551739395,290,10.71926331508213,290S7.418699186991869,290,5.632155301144848,290S0.938692550190808,290,0,290Z"></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the green area will be done dynamically and is based on the area charts axis. Gradient isn't going to work because of this.

Comment: Adjust the stops dynamically based on the chart axis.